# Validar campos vacios por metodo post en php

Tags: php

mi duda esta en que php no reconoce los campos vacíos dentro `$_POST`, el cual contiene el arreglo de mi formulario.

tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
index.php

    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="recibe.php" method="post">

    <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre:" name="nombre">
        <br>

        <label for="hombre">Hombre</label>
        <input type="radio" name="sexo" value="hombre" id="hombre">
        <br>

        <label for="mujer">Mujer</label>
        <input type="radio" name="sexo" value="mujer" id="mujer">
        <br>

        <select name="year" id="year">
            <option value="2000">2000</option>
            <option value="2001">2001</option>
            <option value="2002">2002</option>
        </select>
        <br>

        <label for="terminos">Aceptas los Terminos?</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="terminos" id="terminos" value="ok">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar">


    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Y valido con:

```
recibe.php

<?php
print_r($_POST);

if(!$_POST) {
    header("Location: http://localhost/Formularios/");
}

else
{
    $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
    $sexo = $_POST["sexo"];
    $year = $_POST["year"];
    $Terminos = $_POST["terminos"];

    echo "Hola,".$nombre . " eres:". $sexo;
}

?>
```

Se supone que si no se envía completo el formulario, debe de volver al formulario hasta que todos los datos estén, pero me muestra esto:

```
    Array ( [nombre] => [year] => 2000 )
Notice: Undefined index: sexo in C:\xampp\htdocs\Formularios\recibe.php on line 11

Notice: Undefined index: terminos in C:\xampp\htdocs\Formularios\recibe.php on line 13
Hola, eres:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La solución al problema planteado es la siguiente:

```php
<?php
// Si todos los campos se han enviado, entonces, «$post» será «true»,
// de lo contrario será «false»:
$post = (isset($_POST['nombre']) && !empty($_POST['nombre'])) &&
        (isset($_POST['sexo']) && !empty($_POST['sexo'])) &&
        (isset($_POST['year']) && !empty($_POST['year'])) &&
        (isset($_POST['terminos']) && !empty($_POST['terminos']));


// Si $post es true (verdadero), entonces se mostrarán los resultados:
if ( $post ) {
    $nombre = htmlspecialchars($_POST["nombre"]);
    $sexo = htmlspecialchars($_POST["sexo"]);
    $year = htmlspecialchars($_POST["year"]);
    $terminos = htmlspecialchars($_POST["terminos"]);

  // Resultado
  echo "Hola <strong>$nombre</strong>, eres <strong>$sexo</strong>";
}else {
  // Si en cambio, es false (falso), entonces volverá al formulario desde
  // donde se envió la petición:
  header("Location: ./");
}
?>
```

La razón por la que se te presenta dicho problema, es porque **[$_POST](http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.post.php)** es una variable global de tipo **array asociativo** y por ende, sigue existiendo mientras se envíe peticiones a través del método **POST** del formulario. Eso trae como resultado que no se cumpla la condicional.

Comment: ***$_POST* es una superglobal y existe en todo momento**, aunque no usáramos formularios de ningún tipo, si bien será un array vacío. Entonces si usamos la validación del usuario sin introducir **nada** en el formulario o sin siquiera pasar por el formulario, se produce la redirección, porque $_POST está vacío. Si no existiera el compilador mostraría una notificación de tipo *"Undefined variable"*

Comment: favor de no mandar saludos, no es necesario y no esta bien visto por la comunidad hacerlo en la zona de respuestas

Answer (score 4):

El código que muestras tiene un error en la lógica del programa:

> Se supone que si no se envía completo el formulario, debe de volver al
>   formulario hasta que todos los datos estén...

con la siguiente validación:

```
if (! $_POST) {
    header("Location: http://localhost/Formularios/");
}
```

**Sólo se producirá la redirección si *$_POST*, esta completamente vacio**, es decir que si sólo se introdujera contenido en uno de los campos del formulario, aunque fuera un espacio en blanco, ya no redirecciona.

**Para que todos los campos tengan un contenido, o que en caso contrario, se vuelva al formulario**, una solución posible sería usar la siguiente validación:

```
if (! $_POST
    || trim($_POST['nombre'])   === ''
    || trim($_POST['sexo'])     === ''
    || trim($_POST['year'])     === ''
    || trim($_POST['terminos']) === ''
    ) {
    header("Location: http://localhost/Formularios/");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No te limites a usar si es diferente de vacío (&& !empty), 
Puedes crear tus propios parámetros fácilmente sin depender de los preestablecidos.

Por ejemplo empty significa vacío en cuyo caso si el usuario introduce un espacio en blanco igualmente se enviará el formulario  y el código que escribiste igualmente lo procesará porque no viene “vacío”

En cambio si creas todas las reglas posibles como por ejemplo:

```
If( _Post !=”” And _post !=” “ && _post[0] != “ “
```

Answer (score 0):

Con un foreach recorres todos los campos, se comprueba que nigun valor esté vacío, y si lo está se establece una variable en true, o bien lo manejas con un if, un return o lo que te convenga para el caso

```php
    foreach ($_POST as $param_name => $param_val) {   
    if($param_val == "") $fallo = true;
    // echo "Param: $param_name; Value: $param_val<br />\n";
    }
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).