# problema con la base de datos. no salva los datos inserido despues de ejecutar el script de eliminar

Tags: mysql

Tengo una DB con dos tablas USUARIOS e TBBANCARIO.
El problema esta en cuando ejecuto e script de eliminas datos de la tabla TBBANCARIO y intendo inserir datos atraves del form no salva nada en la tabla TBBANCARIO

```
<!-- SCRIPT DE INSERT  E FORMULARIO-->
```

real_escape_string($_POST['cpf']);
    $numero =$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['numero']);
    $nomebanco = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['nomebanco']);
    $agencia =$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['agencia']);
    $conta=$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['conta']);






    if(cpfExiste($cpf))
        {
            $errors[] = "CPF ja existe";
        }


}



    if(!isset($_SESSION["id_usuario"])){
        header("Location: index.php");
    }

    $idUsuario = $_SESSION['id_usuario'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios INNER JOIN tbbancarios ON usuarios.id = tbbancarios.idusuario WHERE id = '$idUsuario'";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);

    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();



?>

Air Rocket-Cpanel

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" >

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/estilos.css" >

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/fontello.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>


</head>

<body>
    <header>
    <label id="header-label" class="icon-menu1" for="menu-bar"></label>
    <div id="header-top">
        <img id="logo" src="images/logo.png">
            <div class="nav-usuario">
                <nav class="usuario-menu">
                    <a class="ajuda-usuario" href="#"><?php echo ''.utf8_decode($row['nombre'] ); ?></a>

                    <a class="cadastro-usuario" href="#"><?php echo '' .utf8_decode($row['sobrenombre'] )  ; ?></a>
                    <li id="bordes">|</li>
                    <a class="login-usuario" href="logout.php">SAIR</a>

                </nav>
            </div>
    </div>
    </header>

        <input type="checkbox" id="menu-bar">
            <nav id="nav_box" class="menu">

                <li><a href="welcome.php">INICIO</a></li>
                <li id="bordes">|</li>
                <li><a href="minhaconta.php">MINHA CONTA</a></li>
                <li id="bordes">|</li>
                <li><a href="#">COMISSÕES</a></li>


            </nav>
    <div class="container" >
        <div class="row" >

            <div class="row" >
                <div class="col-md-12" id="col-form2" >
                <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table">
                  <thead class="thead-dark">
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="col">CPF</th>
                      <th scope="col">NUMERO BANCO</th>
                      <th scope="col">NOME BANCO</th>
                      <th scope="col">AGENCIA</th>
                      <th scope="col">CONTA</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                   <tbody>
                    <tr>

                      <td> <?php echo '' .utf8_decode($row['cpf'] );?></td>
                    <td> <?php echo '' .utf8_decode($row['numero'] );?></td>
                    <td> <?php echo '' .utf8_decode($row['nomebanco'] );?></td>
                    <td><?php echo '' .utf8_decode($row['agencia'] )  ; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo '' .utf8_decode($row['conta'] );?></td>
                    </tr>

                </tbody>
                </table>
                </div></div>

            </div>

            <div class=" col-md-12" id="col-form">

                <form class="form-inline" id="form-inline" method="POST" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" autocomplete="off">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="cpf" >CPF</label>
                        <div >
                        <input type="text" name="cpf" class="form-control" id="cpf"  placeholder="CPF" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="numero" >Numero do banco</label>
                        <div >
                        <input type="text" name="numero"  class="form-control" id="num_banco" placeholder="Numero do banco" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="nomebanco" >Nome do banco</label>
                        <div >
                        <input type="text"  name="nomebanco"  class="form-control" id="nome_banco" placeholder="Nome do banco">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="agencia">Agencia</label>
                        <div >
                        <input type="text" name="agencia" class="form-control" id="agencia"  placeholder="Agencia">
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="conta">Conta</label>
                        <div>
                        <input type="text" name="conta"  class="form-control" id="conta" placeholder="Conta">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </br>                   

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class=" col-sm-12" id="bnt-guardar">

                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
                        <a href="#" data-href="eliminarcontabanco.php?idbanco=<?php echo $row['idbanco']; ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" ></span> </a>
                    </div>

                </form>
            </br></br></br>
                <div><?php echo resultBlock($errors); ?></div>

            </div>



        </div>

    </div>  

            <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="confirm-delete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">

                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Apagar dados bancarios</h4>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-body">
                    ¿Deseja apagar este registro?
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <a class="btn btn-danger btn-ok">Apagar</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        $('#confirm-delete').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
            $(this).find('.btn-ok').attr('href', $(e.relatedTarget).data('href'));

            $('.debug-url').html('Delete URL: <strong>' + $(this).find('.btn-ok').attr('href') + '</strong>');
        });
    </script>   

    <!--fin modal-->

</body>
```

```
=====================================

<!-- ELIMINAR-->

<?php

require'funcs/conexion.php';


$idbanco = $_GET['idbanco'];

$sql = "DELETE FROM tbbancarios WHERE idbanco = '$idbanco'";
$resultado=$mysqli->query($sql);

    if ($resultado) {
        header("location:minhaconta.php");

} else {
      echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($mysqli);
}
?>
```

==============================

function registraCpf($cpf, $numero, $nomebanco, $agencia, $conta, $idUsuario){

```
    global $mysqli;
    $idUsuario = $_SESSION['id_usuario'];

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO tbbancarios (cpf, numero, nomebanco, agencia, conta, idusuario) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    $stmt->bind_param('sisiii',$cpf, $numero, $nomebanco, $agencia, $conta, $idUsuario);


    if ($stmt->execute()){
        return $mysqli->insert_id;

        } else {
        return 0;   
    }

}
```

Comment: no te guarda/salva nada, por que en ninguna parte estas haciendo un `INSERT`

Comment: Es que insert esta en la carpeta funcs/funcs.php. Ya edite la pregunta.

Comment: Tienes varios errores, empezando por la comprobación de que te llegan datos por  *POST*: `if (!empty($_POST)){` no te asegura que estés recibiendo contenido alguno. Mira el siguiente hilo al respecto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/227366

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow. En ninguna parte del código que muestras llamas a la función `registraCpf` encargada de hacer la inserción.

Comment: @A. Cedano si la llama en require 'funcs/funcs.php';

Comment: No, el hecho de requerir un archivo no implica que la función se ejecute. Es una función, y no se ejecutará hasta que no la llames y le pases los argumentos. El `require` pone el contenido del archivo en el contexto, pero en el caso de las funciones, no se ejecutan nunca solas, hay que llamarlas.

Comment: @A. Cedano sinceramente no entendi lo que me quieres decir. Para ejecutarla función lo ace atraves del form con un ation. El problema está en que al hacer la inserción de los datos en la tabla por primera vez se ejecuta normal, pero despues que hago un test de eliminar de esta tabla y intento inserir denuevo atraves del mismo form no salva nada el la tabla.

Comment: Ya te lo dije anteriormente. A ver si nos aclaramos, ¿esta es la función que debe insertar los datos supongo: `registraCpf`?  ... Pues bien, ¿en qué parte del código llamas a esa función? Como ya dije, el hecho de que hagas un `require` del archivo que contiene esa función no hará que la misma se ejecute. ¿Entiendes eso o no?

Comment: A. Cedano                      
 function registraCpf($cpf, $numero, $nomebanco, $agencia, $conta, $idUsuario){
  
  global $mysqli;
  $idUsuario = $_SESSION['id_usuario'];

  $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO tbbancarios (cpf, numero, nomebanco, agencia, conta, idusuario) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)");
  $stmt->bind_param('sisiii',$cpf, $numero, $nomebanco, $agencia, $conta, $idUsuario);
 
  
  if ($stmt->execute()){
   return $mysqli->insert_id;

   } else {
   return 0; 
  }

 }

Comment: @A. Cedano
oye gracias por insistir con eso, ahora que e visto mi error. añadi lo que me faltaba.

Comment: ¿Ya lo resolviste entonces?

Comment: @A. cedano si lo resolvi, gracias por ayudarme.

Comment: Me alegro entonces de haberte ayudado. Bienvenido a este sitio que es de gran ayuda para la comunidad de programadores de habla hispana.